How to fix Blocked aria-hidden on an element in react-slick?
I'm using the react-slick slider in my React Type script app. When sliding, I get this warning in my console: Blocked aria-hidden on an element because its descendant retained focus. The focus must not be hidden from assistive technology users. Avoid using aria-hidden on a focused element or its ancestor. Element with focus: div
The mentioned div is generated by Slick Library and I can't change it.
Here is my slider setting:export const SliderSettings = () => ({
centerMode: true,
lazyLoad: 'ondemand' as 'ondemand',
centerPadding: "30px",
infinite: false,
slidesToShow: 1,
speed: 500,
arrows: false,
initialSlide: 0,
accessibility: false,
});
